# Problem with Hardware installation

Tags: hardware

I am a new user of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and is very disappointed with this operation system regarding installation of hardware like my Brother DCP- J125 printer,flat bed scanner etc.
I think Linux is not user friendly as a Windows Operating System.The latter OS is much easier to install hardware.
Please can you give me guidance in this regard because I am very frustrating.I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but this really isn't clear. You kinda explain you're having problems with your Brother printer, but you don't give any real details. Also, can you remove all the non useful details? They just make your actual problem harder to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Brother provides the [printer](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-J125) and the [scanner](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html) drivers, together with explicit **installation instructions** for both.

Please read the instructions carefully, particularly the part with the **prerequisites** for 32- and 64-bit systems for the relevant releases of Ubuntu!

Comment: So far,my PC detected my printer.When I give instructions to print a document, the printer is receiving the data but do not print.